# How can I use randjump instead of generating a certain number of random numbers?

Tags: random, julia

I am trying to "skip forward" a few realizations by using the function Future.randjump(), but it doesn't seem to behave as I expect it to. The following code gives me the desired result, where jumping forward 1 steps gives the same result as if I had called `rand(rng)` twice, i.e. the two println display the same number:

```
using Random, Future
rng = MersenneTwister(123);

new_rng = Future.randjump(rng, 1)
rand(rng)
rand(rng)
println(rand(rng))
println(rand(new_rng))
```

However, if I add one extra call to rand(rng) before the call to randjump(), the two printed numbers are completely different:

```
using Random, Future
rng = MersenneTwister(123);

rand(rng)                                # Added line
new_rng = Future.randjump(rng, 1)
rand(rng)
rand(rng)
println(rand(rng))
println(rand(new_rng))
```

I expected that the two calls to `println()` would display the same thing even in the second case, how come they don't? Is there a way I can use `randjump()` in the second case to get the same realizations as if I had called `rand(rng)` several times? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One unit of `randjump` corresponds to generation of two floating point numbers.

Consider this example

```
julia> rng = MersenneTwister(123);

julia> rng2 = Future.randjump(rng, 1);

julia> rand(rng, 4)
4-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.7684476751965699
 0.940515000715187
 0.6739586945680673
 0.3954531123351086

julia> rand(rng2,2)
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.6739586945680673
 0.3954531123351086
```

Note that in the second call (that is `rand(rng2,2)`) the both numbers are identical to the two last numbers in the first call (taht is `rand(rng,2)`).

Another issue is that different distributions might "consume" `Float64` numbers from the stream at a different speed - so you need to check with a particular distribution how fast it consumes floats for the stream (some might also use buffering etc...).

Looking at the source code of `randn` (`@edit randn()`) it consumes one float and hence you get the same results for those two calls:

```
julia> randn(MersenneTwister(123),6)[3:end]
4-element Vector{Float64}:
  1.142650902867199
  0.45941562040708034
 -0.396679079295223
 -0.6647125451916877

julia> randn(Future.randjump(MersenneTwister(123),1),4)
4-element Vector{Float64}:
  1.142650902867199
  0.45941562040708034
 -0.396679079295223
 -0.6647125451916877
```

#### EDIT

Regarding your comment the size of Mersenne Twister state is 19937 bits and half-unit jumps are not supported. Running rand is mutating this state but not half-the way - so you end up with different bits. Note that an RNG is a sequence of states and the actual values are calculated from that state.

The correct pattern to synchronize random numbers in your computations is the following:

```
master_rng = MersenneTwister(123);

rng1 = Future.randjump(master_rng, big(10)^20)
# do whatever you want

rng2 = Future.randjump(master_rng, 2*big(10)^20)
# do whatever you want

rng3 = Future.randjump(master_rng, 3*big(10)^20)
# do whatever you want
```

With this pattern you can correctly maintains synchronization between random number streams and have full control whether the should overlap or not.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I have taken into account that ```randjump``` corresponds to the generation of two floating point numbers, but in the second case I described, jumping one step doesn't seem to give numbers from the same stream at all. Thanks for the point about different distributions, I've edited the code to use the function ```rand()``` instead of ```randn()``` to avoid any such issues, but the problem remains.